# get window scroll or scrollY position in yui

Tags: javascript, yui

In YUI I have following code working for mouse wheel. How do I make this work for a scrollbar?

```
Y.on('mousewheel', function(e) {
     var dir = e.wheelDelta > 0 ? 'Up' : 'Down';
     console.log(dir);
});
```

Thanks for any help...

Comment: The *browser* manages the scrollbars, so why would you need to write Javascript to react to the SB???

Comment: i need data (position) when user is using scrollbar. For code above i get data but only when i use mouse wheel. I want include receiving data when user is interacting with scrollbar on the right

Comment: So what's the problem? Look for an event that is fired on scroll, like https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onscroll or http://help.dottoro.com/ljurkcpe.php etc.
You are limited to what events the browser sends down to Javascript for anything the browser controls. Or you build your own scrollbar and don't use the system one - example: Yahoo Mail, they don't use browser scrollbars for scrolling through the list of emails.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it was a simple solution

```
Y.on('scroll', function(e) {     
     console.log(window.scrollY);
});
```

Comment: yeah there is a 2 days delay :/